# My java is 1.5.0 & javac is 1.6.0_24, does it mean that my Java installation is inconsistent?

Tags: java, debian

I am on Debian Squeeze. My java is 1.5.0 & javac is 1.6.0_24, does it mean that my Java installation is inconsistent? what is the latest package I should be having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [alternatives](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)

It seems your different java programs are pointing to different executables. Debian uses a redirect with links for program for which alternative implementations exists, like java with the gcj, kaffe, sun-java5 and sun-java6, openjdk, ...

In the past you had to swap them all individually with the **update-alternatives** program.

I recollect there was something to do it all at once now : **update-java-alternatives**. It is aprt of the java-commons package. see also [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-java@lists.debian.org/msg11148.html)

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

shows you which java versions are installed

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-openjdk
```

would set all java related programs to point to the openjdk version.

Typically there is a gui tool to help you do this. On my Ubuntu (also debian based) system it System --> Administration --> Alternatives Configurator.

Comment: it is not a link, it is a configuration system for debian. i'll see if I can dig up a link.

Comment: thanks a ton for your answer, it has really helped me solve some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have 2 JDKs installed?

BTW, what does "my Java is 1.5.0" mean? Maybe you have a 1.5.0 JRE with a 1.6.0_24 JDK?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's and your JRE version should be >= JDK to avoid any inconsistencies.